# Random right click on windows Diagnostic

Tags: windows, laptop, touchpad

I have a weird random right click problem on my old Vaio laptop, I'm 90% sure that it's not hardware related because it happens not so often and there is nothing on the touchepad tray icon which indicates touchpad events by green lights on it.

I don't know where should I start for diagnosing but I can't disable touchpad completely to prove the fact that it's not the touchpad related problem (it seems that windows removed the option on the devices menu in settings)

One thing I tried and had solved the problem was disabling pagefile and fast startup (which I can't imagine how these are related) but as soon as I turn pagefile back on the problem happens again. I can't disable pagefile due to my limited 4gb memory but the fast startup is nothing too major for me.

Hard shutdown also works to solve the problem temporarily, but restarting does absolutely zero thing.

Comment: You can disable the touchpad in device manager.

Comment: @Moab There is no disable option, and uninstall makes it comes back as soon as rebooting